# Relation between QT_NO_SSL and QSslSocket::supportsSsl()

Tags: ssl, qt5, qsslsocket

There is a define `QT_NO_SSL`, that is defined if there was no Ssl library found.
There also is the method `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()`.

But how are these two related, are they equivalent?
Does `QT_NO_SSL <=> QSslSocket::supportsSsl() returns false` hold or is it possible that `QT_NO_SSL` is not defined, but `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` returns false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt (at least with the OpenSSL backend) can be compiled:

1. with no SSL support -- `QT_NO_SSL` defined, SSL classes not even available for compilation;
2. with SSL support loaded at runtime => OpenSSL headers must be present at compile time, but QtNetwork won't link to `libssl`/`libcrypto`/...; instead, it will `dlopen` those libraries at runtime looking for the functions it needs;
3. with SSL support linked from QtNetwork.

<sub>The reason for this has to do with the fact that linking QtNetwork to a cryptographic library opens legal problems in terms of redistribution from/to the US. With #3 you *must* have the SSL libraries around or your application won't start, even if you don't need SSL at all; and Qt installers can't "easily" ship those SSL libraries. So instead Qt gets compiled in configuration #2 and *you* have the responsability of installing OpenSSL.</sub>

The scenario in which `QT_NO_SSL` is not defined but `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` returns false is #2 (for instance if Qt fails to find or load a suitable SSL library).

Comment: So you indeed need both to be sure SSL is supported. Thanks!